# Working with various SaaS Applications

Tags: python, cloud, saas

Team,

Good Day. One of the component for our solution requires integrating with various SaaS solutions EX: Amazon,Gmail,Google Drive etc and so many.

Q: Is there a known library or proposal available to work these type of requirement? As such many softwares these days requires with various of these SaaS Apps, so thought of inquiring with you guys to have some inputs.

One such available package i found was libsaas.  Please let me know.

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: Could you please briefly explain what kind of application you are developing and how do you want to integrate with other SaaS apps

Comment: Regarding the "How" question, we want to integrate with few saas applications as mentioned above through their apis and fetch few information. Do you have any idea on any libraries which can be leveraged for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't precise enough as you need to be more specific about what you are trying to integrate with. But boto (https://boto.readthedocs.org) is a library you may want to checkout for working with Amazon services and Google's storage too.Google also maintains a Python API for some of its tools: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/. Hope this helps.